# How is this notation read?

Tags: contest-math

How is this notation read $$a_{0}^{2^{i}}??$$

Here is also an image of the full reference:

[image]

Comment: $a^{2^i}_0 \text{ modulo } p$ can be read as "***A*** zero to the power of two to the ***i*** modulo ***$p$***"

Answer (score 1):

The number $a_0$ is the input to the function that does the exponentiation. The notation
$$a_0^{2^i}$$
then refers to the number $a_0$ to the power of $2^i$.